# The definition of lie group action on vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Under the "The Lie algebra associated with a Lie group" section in the article Lie_group of Wikipedia, it mentions "If G is any group acting smoothly on the manifold M, then it acts on the vector fields" but how does G act on vector fields?

Based on the Lie_group–Lie_algebra_correspondence article, I think for tangent vector field the definition is:

$G$ is Lie group that acts smoothly on smooth manifold $M$,$m$ is point in $M$, $X\in\Gamma (TM)$ then $G$ act on $\Gamma (TM)$ by:

$$ (g\cdot X)_m=dg_{g^{-1}\cdot m}(X_{g^{-1}\cdot m})  $$

where $dg_{g^{-1}\cdot m}$ is the differential of the map $m \to g\cdot m$ at $g^{-1}\cdot m$

Is that correct? Can it be defined for general vector fields?

Comment: yes and yes, diffeomorphisms act on vector fields

Comment: the space of vector fields*

Comment: @Timkinsella Is there some reference about how is it defined for general vector fields? The way for tangent vector field seems not easy to be extended to general vector field.

Comment: youve given the correct def for vector fields.  maybe youre taking about the restriction of a vector field to a submanifold, so that vectors do not necessarily lie in the tangent space to the submanifold.  in that case a diffeomorphism of the submanifold probably wont act of the space of "vector fields" in a sensible way

Comment: in the wiki article when they say "vector field" they mean what you mean when you say "tangent vector field"